# How to restrict mongodb's ROM usage on 32 bit architecture system? I am using mongodb version 2.4

Tags: database, mongodb, debian

I am using mongodb version 2.4 due to 32 bit system limitation (nanopi m1 plus). I have a debian jessie OS image (Debian 8) with 4.2 GB space available (emmc). I have a total of about 2.2 GB available after loading my application files. However, my flash gets filled up quickly to 100% after I start running my application.
Then I get the error "Unable to get database instance and mongodb stopped  working " and my application stops working.
Can someone please help me with this problem. Thanks in advance!

Memory status of my device when it stopped working:
`df –h`:

`Filesystem- overlay  Size- 4.2G  Used- 4.2G  Avail- 0   Use%- 100%   Mounted on- /`

[df -h command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egx1m.jpg)

`du –shx /var/lib/mongodb/ | sort –rh | head  –n 20`

```
512M    /var/lib/mongodb/xyz.6
512M    /var/lib/mongodb/xyz.5
257M    /var/lib/mongodb/xyz.4
128M    /var/lib/mongodb/xyz.3
64M     /var/lib/mongodb/xyz.2
32M     /var/lib/mongodb/xyz.1
17M     /var/lib/mongodb/xyz.ns
17M     /var/lib/mongodb/xyz.0
16M     /var/lib/mongodb/local.ns
16M     /var/lib/mongodb/local.0
4.0K     /var/lib/mongodb/journal
0          /var/lib/mongodb/mongodb.lock
```

`du –shx /var/lib/mongodb/journal/* | sort –rh | head –n 20`

```
257M /var/lib/mongodb/journal/prealloc.2
257M /var/lib/mongodb/journal/prealloc.1
257M /var/lib/mongodb/journal/prealloc.0
```

`du –shx /var/log/mongodb/journal/* | sort –rh | head –n 20`

```
399M  /var/lib/mongodb/mongodb.log
353M  /var/lib/mongodb/mongodb.log.1
3.3M  /var/lib/mongodb/mongodb.log.2.gz
752K  /var/lib/mongodb/mongodb.log.1.gz
```

Comment: mmapv1 has prealloc and smallfiles options you could try.

Comment: @D.SM Thanks. I changed my mongo.conf file as below to save space but my mongodb service keeps stopping now.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply

Comment: This my mongodb.conf file now
`# mongodb.conf
# Where to store the data.
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
journal = false
smallfiles = true
nssize = 10
noprealloc = true
quota = true
quotaFiles = 2`

Comment: When the service stops, I am able to restart it manually using following commands as a root user:
`cd /var/lib/mongodb
rm mongodb.lock
mongodb --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb --repair
chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
service mongodb restart`

These commands work and I am able to restart mongodb, but after I shut down my system and start again (power cycle), I face the same issue that mongodb has stopped.

Comment: https://github.com/p-mongo/mongodb-faq#server-log